# How can i binding string length zero-value in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I need express to string length.
so, i just to do this.

```
<div>
<input type='text' ng-model="inputValue">
<span>Your input key count : {{inputValue.length}}</span>
<div>
```

result.
no input => "" (empty)
some key input => 1 or 2 or 3 (correct length)

I think that length 0 value was not show.
but I need zero-value. how can i show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to care about initialization do something like this:

```
<div>
  <input type='text' ng-model="inputValue" >
  <span>Your input key count : {{inputValue ? inputValue.length : 0}}</span>
<div>
```

Comment: This solution is not ideal. Consider this, the `inputValue` could also be a function that is returning an array value as output and you have to get its `length`. You could use `ngInit` or you can call that function multiple times; once to check whether it returns any value or secondly to get its length. That way its running the function multiple times.

Comment: To this, I've provided a solution below. [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28346042/2642351)

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the inputValue with an empty String. You can do this by adding ng-init

```
<div>
  <input type='text' ng-model="inputValue" ng-init="inputValue=''">
  <span>Your input key count : {{inputValue.length}}</span>
<div>
```

Comment: You might want to double-check your apostrophes at the `ng-init`.

Answer (score 0):

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgao0h1h/)

Controller:

```
    $scope.inputValue = "";
```

Html:

```
 <div>
                <input type='text' ng-model="inputValue">
                <span>Your input key count : {{inputValue.length}}</span>
            </div>
```

Comment: I was about to add this as the answer....well created the fiddle you can use :) http://jsfiddle.net/hgao0h1h/

Answer (score 0):

The best way or the ideal method to show '0' in view when the output of a length of a variable is '0' is to use `.toString()`.

Like in your case, the answer could have been :

```
<div>
<input type='text' ng-model="inputValue">
<span>Your input key count : {{inputValue.length.toString()}}</span>
<div>
```